# How to send interrupt/ ctrl C during execution of expect script

Tags: shell, expect, sigint, keyboardinterrupt

I am trying to execute some commands and one of which will not come back to console and need to explicitly bring it using ctrl+ c. After that I need to execute some more commands in that script.

```
expect "$ "
send "sh /root/jboss-eap-6.3/bin/standalone.sh\r"
set timeout 10

expect "$ "
```

I have to run other commands after executing standalone.sh script. But it will hold and not come back to console.
I tried

```
trap {
    send \x03
    send_user "You pressed Ctrl+C\n"
} SIGINT
```

.
But that also didn't worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of ways to kill a process in `bash`. If you by some chance know the name of your (jboss eap) process you could run `pkill processName`, `killall processName` or `kill pidof processName` instead of trying to send key-strokes.

Comment: I don't want to kill that process, it will come to a point like it started the process and no changes. I have to just come out of it.

Comment: "come out of it" is very much the same as "kill"